# Visual Studio и программирование на C

Tags: c, visual-studio

Я слышал, что в Visual Studio можно программировать на С, создавая С++ проект и переименовывая файл с кодом в формат *.c.
Подскажите, компилятор полностью поддерживает С или все таки присутствуют какие-то досадные ограничения?
К примеру я заметил, что не компилируются программы с printf,scanf,gets...
Компилятор требует использовать безопасные функции с постфиксом _s (Пример gets_s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio полностью стандарт C99 не поддерживает, хотя поддерживается многое. `printf`, `scanf` - поддерживаются, просто Вам выдаются предупреждения, что они не безопасны. 
Поэтому, строго говоря, полноценно(т.е. с использованием всех доступных фич) на C, используя Visual Studio, писать нельзя. Но для очень многих задач VS будет достаточно. Если я не ошибаюсь, `ffmpeg` компилируется MSVC2013, а это говорит о многом.

Небольшая цитата от Герба Саттера:

> If you really need <...> features in C95/C99/C11 that are not part of
>   ISO C++ <...> then we recommend that you consider using a different
>   compiler such as Intel or gcc

**Обновление**:
Несколько альтернативных IDE для Windows из комментариев:

- [CLion + MinGW](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)
- [QtCreator + MinGW](https://www.qt.io/ru/download-open-source/)
- [Eclipse + MinGW](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/heliossr2)

Ещё можно попробовать использовать [clang в Visual Studio](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html), но я не уверен, что этот проект дорос до релизного качества.

**Обновление 2:**
Т.к. моё заявление о неполноценной поддержки студией разработки на языке C вызвало спор, приведу здесь одну фичу из C99, которую студия не поддерживает: [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Это, разумеется, не единственное отличие, но одно из наиболее ярко выраженных. Есть ещё список [здесь](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm), но он не учитывает, что часть C99 перекочевала в C++11. Подобного списка для современности я не нашёл, но отличия есть и они могут стать камнем преткновения при разработке. Хотя повторюсь, ffmpeg студией(по заявлению MS) собирается, а это говорит о том, что многое всё-таки поддерживается. Но на полную поддержку расcчитывать не стоит, и если Вы хотите использовать C со всем функционалом, то стоит пройти мимо компилятора MSVC++ - это компилятор для C++, а не C.

Comment: А какие-нибудь удобные аналоги по типу Visual Studio есть, кроме Rad Studio? Нет ли каких-нибудь расширений для Visual Studio?

Comment: Есть `CLion`, я не использовал, но JetBrains внушает доверие

Comment: "А какие-нибудь удобные аналоги" - под XP я использую либо бесплатную  студию с `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` по всем файлам проекта, либо Eclipse в связке с MinGW. У последнего варианта проблем с C нет вообще никаких.

Comment: @klopp, `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` - можно добавить в настройки проекта, тогда не надо добавлять в каждый файл

Comment: Ещё `QtCreator` можно использовать, хотя я от него не в восторге(с другой стороны я его больше года уже не использовал, может чего поменялось)

Comment: Задефайнить в каждом файле != добавлять туда руками :) У меня в каждом проекте есть файл "config.h", в котором всё и происходит в зависимости от текущей OS и/или компилятора. Настройки проектов при этом не трогаются вообще и они переносятся с платформы на платформу один в один. Но это уже кому как удобней, конечно.

Comment: @ixSci, пожалуйста, укажите выдержки из C99, которые не поддерживаются в VS, раз уж так категорично открещиваетесь от VS. К тому же, вопрос был как раз о том, "что не поддерживается", а не "кто не поддерживает". Строго говоря, полностью стандарт не поддерживает и GCC.

Comment: @mega, я не знаю C. Даже если бы знал, я бы не стал этим заниматься. MSVC поддерживает из C99/C11 лишь то, что вошло в стандарт C++, на всё остальное рассчитывать не стоит. Как сказал Саттер: *"If you really need <...> features in C95/C99/C11 that are not part of ISO C++ <...> then we recommend that you consider using a different compiler such as Intel or gcc"*. MSVC это C++ компилятор - не C.

Comment: А при чем тогда "полноценно на C с использованием Visual Studio писать нельзя"? Вы тогда уж уточните эту свою мысль, т.к. это бред, если понимать дословно.

Comment: @mega, по-моему в моём ответе всё кристально ясно. MSVC не поддерживает стандарт C в полной мере, поэтому писать на C, с использованием MSVC, *полноценно*, нельзя. Я не понимаю, что ещё тут можно сказать.

Comment: @mega, немного добавил пояснение. Больше не вижу я, что ещё можно добавить. Должно быть всё предельно ясно.

Comment: Предельно ясно будет, если Вы обозначите границы *полноценного Си*, в которые не укладывается стандарт из C++98, который, в свою очередь, полностью поддерживается VS. Как я уже писал, приведите конкретные примеры из стандарта C99, чтобы не быть голословным.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23611/discussion-between-ixsci-and-mega).